# Laptop power supply with hot foam cutter?

Tags: power-supply

I wish to make a hot foam cutter with variable control. The circuit I have in mind will go as follows:

1. Cheap rotary dimmer switch to gfci outlet.
2. 16V, 2.5A laptop power supply plugged into said gfci outlet.
3. hot foam cutter powered by the DC output of the supply.

Does this sound good and safe?

Comment: Try a cheap laptop supply with a cheap motor PWM controller... since cheap is what it sounds like you are going for.

Answer (score 3):

Most laptop power supplies use a switchmode voltage regulator, so you probably won't be able to control the current through your wire with the dimmer.

Comment: Will I be able to control the voltage though?

Comment: No. The voltage regulator in the laptop supply will try to keep the output voltage constant, until the input voltage drops too low for it to work correctly.  (and voltage and current cannot be controlled independently - they are related by Ohm's Law, and the resistance of your cutting wire.)

Comment: Removing the regulator would probably cause damage to other components inside the power supply?

Comment: The regulator in a laptop power supply is an integral part of the conversion and isolation of the DC output from the AC mains input.  It would not be a separate unit that can be removed, leaving an unregulated DC source.

Comment: Ok I'll start reading about transformers then. Thanks for the answers.